# angular - can't run rxjs interval with angular universal

Tags: angular, rxjs

I made a carousel effect through the RXJS's interval timing to change parameter.

I found that it works in development mode(ng serve), but it does not work properly in the `universal` mode, It's can't enter the page.

For example:

```
n: number = 0;
max: number = 5;

constructor(){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.carousel();
}

carousel() {
  this.subscription = interval(2000).subscribe(() => {
      //In universal, the console.log message show in node.js background log message not in browser console message. Each time the page is reorganized, it will be executed once and cannot be destroyed.
      console.log(`show the photo: ${this.n}`);
      if (this.n>this.max){
        this.n = 0;
      }else{
       this.n = this.n+1;
      }
  }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I found in `universal` model, assume that the carousel effect is on the page `B`, you can successfully enter page B through the link on page `A`, but opening page B directly will fail.

I tried to start the carousel in `ngAfterContentInit()` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I'm struggling whole day.

Comment: @DawidZbiński Do you use angular universal? I found the problem there.

Comment: @DawidZbiński I have already answered my question, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yeah I actually fixed it and forget to reply to you. After all, it pretty much makes sense. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9):

If you use angular universal, you need to use `isPlatformBrowser` to exclude code that can only run on the front end.

Eaxmple:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { PLATFORM_ID } from "@angular/core";

constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) { }

do(){
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      //do something, only runs on the front end
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like interval and timer from rxjs does not work with Server Rendering!

Comment: Just to add proper context here, the interval _does_ in fact work with server rendering. The problem you experienced is because Universal expects rendering to _end_ and it waits for the interval to stop - but it never does. So your page renders server side, and then never returns because it's running the interval.