# Can't set a timeout with timer RxJS operator in angular lifecycle hooks

Tags: angular, rxjs, timeout, angular17

I sat a timeout with timer operator from RxJS in ngOnChanges hook but I couldn't load my app in browser. When I comment the timeout app runs. I tried other hooks and same problem happened. I don't get any errors in console or runtime just the browser loading spinner keeps spinning

```js
$currentEventTimer$?: Subscription;

currentEvent: SliderEvent = {
    id: '1',
    type: 'VIDEO',
    title: 'concerts next month',
    description: "Don't miss your favorite artist's concert",
    file: '',
    time: 5000
  };

next(): void {
  if (this.currentEventIndex != this.events.length - 1)
    this.currentEvent = this.events[++this.currentEventIndex];
  else this.currentEvent = this.events[(this.currentEventIndex = 0)];

  this.$currentEventTimer$?.unsubscribe();

  if (this.currentEvent.time)
    this.$currentEventTimer$ = timer(this.currentEvent.time).subscribe(() =>
      this.next()
    );
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  this.$currentEventTimer$?.unsubscribe();

  if (this.currentEvent.time)
    this.$currentEventTimer$ = timer(this.currentEvent.time).subscribe(() =>
      this.next()
    );
}
```

This is my environment:

```
Angular CLI: 17.1.2  
Node: 20.10.0  
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0  
OS: linux x64  
Browser: Chrome 121.0.6167.139  

Angular: 17.1.2  
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms  
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server  
... router, ssr

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1701.2  
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.1.2  
@angular-devkit/core            17.1.2  
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.1.2  
@schematics/angular             17.1.2  
rxjs                            7.8.1  
typescript                      5.2.2  
zone.js                         0.14.2
```

I am making a slider that has a timer and when timer ends I want component loads next slide. I expected to set a timeout for the first time when component loads with ngOnChanges hook.

Comment: Check for ssr: `if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) { timer(...)...; }` and `constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any){}`

Comment: thanks it worked. I'm wondering why i couldn't set timeout? @Pieterjan

Comment: Don't know exactly, but [`interval`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval) and [`timer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer), any time-related operator doesn't work during SSR (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370609/angular-cant-run-rxjs-interval-with-angular-universal#comment-136688264) too)